# "delay" inclusion of separate file in PHP?

Tags: php, class

At the very top of my page/site, before `<!doctype html>` etc., I load my classes with `spl_autoload_register()`.

One of the classes is `site`, and inside this class I have a static function:

```
<?php
/**
 *  A fast and easy way to include content to a page...
 *  "dir_pages_contents" is a defined constant with the path to the content files
 */
public static function include_content($content_name){
    if(file_exists(dir_pages_contents.$content_name.'.cont.php')){
        include dir_pages_contents.$content_name.'.cont.php';
    } else {
        /*  echo an error message  */
    }
}
?>
```

I was hoping to do something like this i practice:

1. create a new document with some content and save it with the extension `.cont.php` into a folder specified for page contents.
2. Then; On the page where I want this content to be displayed - I do:

   site::include_content('test_doc');

This almost works; The document, or content, is included and displayed.
But it seems like it is included where the class is - at the very top where the class is - because PHP-variables set outside of this document is not available within the document at all.

Here's a illustration of the setup:

**test_doc.cont.php**

```
<?=$hello?>
```

**index.php**

```
<!--  PHP-classes are included here  -->
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php $hello = 'Im outside...'; ?>

<!--  this includes the document, but the variable $hello is not  -->
<?=site::include_content('test_doc')?>

<!--  this works perfectly  -->
<?php include dir_pages_contents.'test_doc.cont.php; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

The inclusion of a separate file, or document, is done immediately when the `include`-statement is read by the script i guess? but not displayed until futher down the script where the function was called?

Any suggestion for another way to accomplish this?

I'm not looking for any MVC or other PHP-framework.

**EDIT:**
*user1612290* pointed out to me that the `include`-statement within my `include_content`-function only uses the variable scope of my function - meaning that any variables decleared outside my `include_content` is not passed to the include directive unless I make them `global`.

It was also suggested that I could pass an array of named `keys=>$variables` into my function and use `extract()` on them to make them available.

This is what I came up with:
- added $arr

```
public static function include_content($content_name,$arr){
    if(file_exists(dir_pages_contents.$content_name.'.cont.php')){
        if (is_array($arr)){extract($arr);}
        include dir_pages_contents.$content_name.'.cont.php';
    } else {
        /*  echo an error message  */
    }
}
```

Now I'm able to do this:

```
<?=site::include_content('test_doc',array('hello'=>$hello))?>
```

Allthoug I'm not happy with this solution, I now have the variables accessable within the included document - so I'm closer than I was an hour ago :)

Any easier way?

Comment: Your include within the `include_content` function uses the variable scope of that function, meaning that any variables declared outside of that function will not be passed to the `include` directive unless you `global` them inside the function first. Consider passing a named-key array of data to be passed into the `site::include_content` function that can be run through the `extract()` function inside `include_content()` to pass data.

Comment: Meaning I would have to add an array with all the variables I intend to use within the included document? e.g. `site::include_content('test_doc',$arr=array($var1,$var2,$var3,...)´.

Comment: Yes. I [wrote a function](https://bitbucket.org/mnbayazit/php-utilities/src/eede78e4ee5cb1f5c35b3bb31e3568daa2f52158/utilities/Str.php?at=default#cl-14) for this, if it's of any use to you.

Comment: yep, it's basically the same as what I came up with...  
But I don't really like having  `array('var'=>$var,'var2'=>$var2,'var3'=>$var3,...)` as the second arguement in the function... It makes it not as smooth as I was hoping for...